# Passing argument in java through CLI

Tags: java

While passing arguments in *Java* through *CLI* we generally pass like

```
java -cp jar classname "args[0]" "args[1]"
```

I want to pass arguments like
`--host hostname --user username --password password` and so on.

Please help me in achieving this.

Thanks in Advance !!

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200054/java-library-for-parsing-command-line-parameters

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use **commons-cli** library as follows:

```
import org.apache.commons.cli.*;

public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Options options = new Options();

        Option host = new Option("h", "host", true, "host address");
        host .setRequired(true);
        options.addOption(host);

        Option user = new Option("u", "user", true, "user login");
        user.setRequired(true);
        options.addOption(user);

        Option password = new Option("p", "password", true, "user's password");
        password.setRequired(true);
        options.addOption(password);

        CommandLineParser parser = new DefaultParser();
        HelpFormatter formatter = new HelpFormatter();
        CommandLine cmd;

        try {
            cmd = parser.parse(options, args);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            formatter.printHelp("my-program", options);

            System.exit(1);
            return;
        }

        String inputHost = cmd.getOptionValue("host");
        String inputUser = cmd.getOptionValue("user");
        String inputPassword = cmd.getOptionValue("password");


    }

}
```

Comment: Glad to hear it :) Would you mind to mark the answer as the solution? Thanks. @NamanAgarwal

Answer (score 4):

> *In 2022, there are better libraries for building CLI applications than Apache Commons CLI.*

Consider using [picocli](https://picocli.info/) to get an ultra-compact program that automatically has colored help and optionally has command line autocompletion.

Your program could look like this:

```java
@Command(name = "myapp", description = "Does cool stuff.", mixinStandardHelpOptions = true)
class MyApp implements Callable<Integer> {
    @Option(names = {"-s", "--host"}, required = true, description = "host name")
    String hostname;

    @Option(names = {"-u", "--user"}, required = true, description = "user name")
    String username;

    @Option(names = {"-p", "--password"}, interactive = true, description = "pass phrase")
    char[] password;

    public Integer call() {
        // business logic here...
        System.out.printf("host=%s, user=%s%n", hostname, username);
        return 0; // exit code signalling normal termination
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // in 1 line, parse the args, handle errors,
        // handle requests for help/version info, call the business logic
        // and obtain an exit status code:

        int exitCode = new CommandLine(new MyApp()).execute(args);
        System.exit(exitCode);
    }
}
```

Some advantages of using picocli:

[image: colored usage help for MyApp]

- The command name, options and option parameters use ANSI colors and styles for contrast with the other text. This doesn’t just look good, it also **reduces the cognitive load** on the user, making your app more user-friendly.
- By implementing `Callable` or `Runnable`, you can set up and execute your program in **one line of code** in the `main` method. The business logic goes in the `call` (or `run`) method.
- The `mixinStandardHelpOptions = true` means that `--help` and `--version` options are added automatically. These work as expected without requiring further coding.
- You get some nice **security benefits** for free: this program will prompt the user for their password, and users can type in their password without it being echoed to the console. Also, the password is captured in a `char[]` array so it can be nulled out from memory when the work is done - these are good security practices.

See [Autocomplete for Java Command Line Applications](https://picocli.info/autocomplete.html) for adding TAB autocompletion to this program.

*Disclaimer: I maintain picocli.*

Answer (score 0):

Use `longOpt`.

Example:

```
options.addOption(Option.builder().argName("date")
        .desc("The start date (YYYY-MM-DD) from where to retrieve information.").hasArg(true).longOpt("sd")
        .numberOfArgs(1).required(false).build());
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this easily just the same as you would for parsing normal program arguments. Here is a small example:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(args));
        String host = args[1];
        String user = args[3];
        String password = args[5];
        System.out.println("Host: " + host);
        System.out.println("User: " + user);
        System.out.println("Password: " + password);
    }
}
```

If I run this program with the following command:

```
java Main --host hostname --user username --password password
```

This is the output:

```
[--host, hostname, --user, username, --password, password]
Host: hostname
User: username
Password: password
```

Alternatively, you can use a library like the Apache Commons CLI which includes a lot of utilities to parse command line arguments and options:

```
import org.apache.commons.cli.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Options options = new Options();
        Option host = Option.builder()
                .longOpt("host")
                .hasArg()
                .valueSeparator(' ')
                .build();
        Option user = Option.builder()
                .longOpt("user")
                .hasArg()
                .valueSeparator(' ')
                .build();
        Option password = Option.builder()
                .longOpt("password")
                .hasArg()
                .valueSeparator(' ')
                .build();
        options.addOption(host);
        options.addOption(user);
        options.addOption(password);

        CommandLineParser parser = new DefaultParser();
        try {
            CommandLine line = parser.parse(options, args);
            System.out.println("Host: " + line.getOptionValue("host"));
            System.out.println("User: " + line.getOptionValue("user"));
            System.out.println("Pass: " + line.getOptionValue("password"));

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            System.err.println("Parsing failed. Reason: " + e.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

However, this route requires you to add the Apache Commons CLI to your classpath and include it with your program (or add it as a dependency for a dependency management program like Maven or Gradle). It might seem like more work, but the Apache Commons CLI is very powerful and flexible and can make parsing a lot of command line options much less painful.

Here is the output of that sample class with the Apache Commons CLI:

```
Host: hostname
User: username
Password: password
```